# Django: Using expressions on related fields in extra or order_by

Tags: python, django

**I need to calculate and order by an expression in django. What's the most efficient way to do this?**

Example setup:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(...)
    prev = models.ForeignKey('Rating')
```

I have to calculate the difference of the current rating and the previous and order by it. I have a few methods that work.

**Method 1:** Use `extra()` to add an extra select clause that calculates the diff. However this depends on the way Django labels joined tables in the SQL query. Example:

```
Rating.objects.filter(prev__isnull=False)\
        .select_related('prev')\
        .extra(select={'diff': 'rating.rating - T3.rating'})\
        .order_by('-diff')
```

(In my case the joined table was named `T3` since I actually have a second related field in my model)

**Method 2:** Add an extra field to the model.

**Method 3:** Do the sorting in python. Very inefficient.

**What I'd like:** Being able to use `F` expressions in the extra `select` clause, like so:

```
Rating.objects.filter(prev__isnull=False)\
        .extra(select={'diff': F('rating') - F('prev__rating')})\
        .order_by('-diff')
```

or possibly in the `order by` clause:

```
Rating.objects.filter(prev__isnull=False)\
        .order_by(F('rating') - F('prev__rating'))
```

This is perhaps a question better asked to the Django devs but I want to see what ideas you have.